# Passing parameters to a job in Quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler, command-line-arguments

Presently I have a code that has a java main method and which takes few command line args for its execution. I am in the process of making this as a quartz job, I would like to pass the arguments to this job.

Is there a way I can do it? I did some analysis on the JobDataMap but I am not sure if I can use it for this purpose.

Also, this job is going to be  one time job that requires pause and continue kind of actions from the user. What kind of job should I extend or use for this case w.r.t quartz?

Thanks a bunch for your time.

Cheers,
Abi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, yes JobDataMap is here to let you pass parameters to your job, no problem about using it for that purpose !

Second, the question is not which Job to extend (Job class must be sufficient) but more - which trigger to use ?

- [Cron Trigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html) may help

Don't know exactly which user interaction you need, but you must be able to achieve your goal using [Standby](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/SchedulerStandby.html)

Comment: @Abhishek nope ! don't forget to accept answer if your ok with it ;)

Comment: @Alois: One more question related...could I set the max execution time of job? which includes the logic of negation of paused time..?

Comment: @Alois: Marked it as answered...some help on the max execution time would be greatly helpful :)

Comment: @Abhishek what you mean by max execution time ? you want your job to stop/pause if he exceed a certain amount of time ?

Comment: @Aliis: Example : I want my job to run for one minute - if the job is paused at 30 seconds...and resumed back it has to run for the remaining 30 seconds..something of this kind...